# Whats the overhead of creating a Log4j Logger

Tags: java, log4j

I have some webservices in my application and i want to log them to diferent files, based on the webservice name. For that i am creating loggers with

```
myLogger = Logger.getLogger(logKey);
```

I am wondering if i should cache these loggers to avoid creating them for every call, or can i ignore the overhead.

Comment: Don't trust what people tell you... use the source!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Loggers are already cached by log4j using the default log repository (`Hierarchy`). In other words, it's just a hashtable lookup.

However, in my experience you *tend* to make the logger static, so it only ends up being called once per class anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't making the logger static prevent you from changing its level at runtime (through an MBean for example)?
In theory not, but I thought that was the case with java logging.

Comment: I don't *think* so. I think the level stuff is checked dynamically, rather than being frozen in the constructed logger.

Comment: Here's the link to the respective caching code in log4j-core: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/4ed4d281ff5775ba4cd5bdf3c61854cc6fab8657/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.java#L500-L520

Answer (score 9):

This method Logger.getLogger(logKey) looks in logger cache for a logger with the name passed in logKey. If it doesn't exist it creates one. First call for a logger name, a Logger will be created but later calls will get it from cache so you don't need to handle 
this in your code.