# Log4J: Strategies for creating Logger instances

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I decided to use Log4J logging framework for a new Java project. 
I am wondering what strategy should I use for creating/managing Logger instances and why?

- one instance of Logger per class
  e.g.

  ```
  class Foo {
      private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
  }
  ```
- one instance of Logger per thread
- one instance of Logger per application
- horizontal slicing : one instance of Logger in each layer of an application (e.g. the view layer, the controller layer and the persistence layer)
- vertical slicing : one instance of Logger within functional partitions of the application

Note: This issue is already considered to some extent in these articles:

[Whats the overhead of creating a Log4j Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771675/whats-the-overhead-of-creating-a-log4j-logger)

Comment: Note: The "ultimate" way is most likely investigating the call stack to get the caller.  In my experience Java programs are more robust if you explicitly code things, instead of rely on getting it magically.

Comment: A bug in the JRE will cause the logging to be incorrect.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Typically, you'd have loggers setup per class because that's a nice logical component.  Threads are already part of the log messages (if your filter displays them) so slicing loggers that way is probably redundant.

Regarding application or layer based loggers, the problem is that you have to find a place to stick that Logger object.  Not a really big deal.  The bigger issue is that some classes may be used at multiple levels of from multiple applications... it could be difficult to get your logger right.  Or at least tricky.

...and the last thing you want is bad assumptions in your logging setup.

If you care about applications and layers and have easy separation points, the NDC is the way to go.  The code can be a little excessive sometimes but I don't know how many times I've been saved by an accurate context stack showing me that Foo.bar() was called from application X in layer Y.

Comment: How about if I have a singelton class which has a static instance of the logger? and make all classes access this member of the singelton class?

Answer (score 33):

The strategy that is most used is to create a logger per class. If you create new threads give them a usefull name, so their logging is easily distinguishable.

Creating loggers per class has the benefit of being able to switch on/off logging in the package structure of your classes:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache = INFO
log4j.logger.com.example = DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.example.verbose = ERROR
```

The above would set all apache library code to `INFO` level, switch logging from your own code to `DEBUG` level with the exception of the verbose package.

Comment: I see the benefit if you want to control logging level by package structure.  Is there a better way to achieve this than copying `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);` to each class?

Comment: Given that you need some way to provide a logger instance both your package- and classname, I don't see an alternative to creating one per class. If you would create logger per package, you still would need to retrieve a reference to the logger instance in order to use it.

Comment: Which `Logger` constructor do you use do create a `Logger` for a package? Is it `getLogger(String name)` where name is just a String specifying the package (ie: "a.b.c")?  If you do that can you configure the logging level as you mention a la `log4j.logger.a.b.c = INFO`?

Comment: Yes, I think you would use the String variant as in `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getPackage());` The logger hierarchy also works if you create loggers with names "a.b", "a.b.c", etc. See the manual at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 14):

I'm certain this isn't a best practice, but I've sacked some startup time on applications before to save lines of code.  Specifically, when pasting in:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

...developers often forget to change "MyClass" to the current class name, and several loggers always wind up pointing at the wrong place.  This Is Bad.

I've occasionally written:

```
static Logger logger = LogUtil.getInstance();
```

And:

```
class LogUtil {
   public Logger getInstance() {
      String callingClassName = 
         Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClass().getCanonicalName();
      return Logger.getLogger(callingClassName);
   }
}
```

The "2" in that code might be wrong, but the gist is there; take a performance hit to (on class load, as a static variable) find the class name, so that a developer doesn't really have a way to mistype this or introduce any error.

I'm generally not thrilled with losing performance to prevent developer error at runtime, but if it happens as a singleton, once?  Often sounds like a good trade to me.

Comment: I updated your answer - it didn't compile, and I used getClass().getCanonicalName() instead of just getClassName(). Oh, and 2 is indeed the magic number.

Comment: I've written a similar class for the reasons you stated. So that all is needed is: static final ClassLogger log = new ClassLogger(); I've incorporated slf4j to permit many log implementations. For details see org.sormula.log.ClassLogger found at www.sormula.org.

Comment: Using getStackTrace()[2].getClass().getCanonicalName(), you will always get "java.lang.StackTraceElement".  I got the results I wanted using 'callingClassName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName()'.  I voted for the answer, but did not edit it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have tried your LogUtil on my Spring boot project. It is printing "[pool-2-thread-6] j.l.StackTraceElement" instead of class name

Answer (score 10):

As has been said by others, I would create a Logger per class:

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

or

```
private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

However, I have found it useful in the past to have other information in the logger. For instance, if you have a web site, you could include the user ID in every log message. That way,, you can trace everything a user is doing (very useful for debugging problems etc).

The easiest way to do this is to use an MDC, but you can use a Logger created for each instance of the class with the name including the user ID.

Another advantage of using an MDC is if you use SL4J, you can change the settings depending upon the values in your MDC. So if you wish to log all activity for a particular user at DEBUG level, and leave all of the other users at ERROR, you can. You can also redirect different output to different places depending upon your MDC.

Some useful links:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html

http://www.slf4j.org/api/index.html?org/slf4j/MDC.html

Comment: I like the `this.getClass()` part. In this way there won't be any copy/paste errors regarding the logger name.

Answer (score 4):

- Create one logger per class.
- If you have dependencies that require *Commons Logging* (quite likely) use slf4j's [bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) for Commons Logging. Instantiate your loggers (per class) using the Commons Logging interface: `private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);`
- Manifest this pattern in your IDE using shortcuts. I use IDEA's [live templates](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/tag/live-templates/) for this purpose.
- Provide contextual information to threads using an [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) (thread local stack of strings) or an [MDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) (thread local map of String → ?).

Examples for templates:

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog($class$.class); // live template 'log'

if (log.isDebugEnabled())
    log.debug(String.format("$string$", $vars$)); // live template 'ld', 'lw', 'le' ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Option : You can try **[AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/)** crosscutting on logging. Check **[here : *Simplify Your Logging**](https://web.archive.org/web/20100303172318/https://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3109831/Simplify-your-logging-with-AspectJ.htm)*. (If you don't want to use **[AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)**, you can look **[slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)**)

```
//Without AOP

    Class A{
       methodx(){
        logger.info("INFO");
       }
    }
    
    Class B{
       methody(){
        logger.info("INFO");
       }
    }
    
//With AOP
    
    Class A{
       methodx(){
         ......
       }
    }
    
    Class B{
       methody(){
         ......
       }
    }
    
    Class LoggingInterceptor{

       //Catched defined method before process
       public void before(...xyz){
         logger.info("INFO" + ...xyz);
       }
    
       //Catched defined method after processed          
       public void after(...xyz){
         logger.info("INFO" + ...xyz);
       }
       .....
    
    }
```

**P.S :** **[AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)** will be better, it is **[DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)** way.

Answer (score 2):

the best and easiest method to create custom loggers, notlinked to any classname  is:

```
// create logger
Logger customLogger = Logger.getLogger("myCustomLogName");

// create log file, where messages will be sent, 
// you can also use console appender
FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(), 
                                             "/home/user/some.log");

// sometimes you can call this if you reuse this logger 
// to avoid useless traces
customLogger.removeAllAppenders();

// tell to logger where to write
customLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);

 // send message (of type :: info, you can use also error, warn, etc)
customLogger.info("Hello! message from custom logger");
```

now, if you need another logger in same class, no problem :) just create new one

```
// create logger
Logger otherCustomLogger = Logger.getLogger("myOtherCustomLogName");
```

now see the code above and create new fileappender so your output will be sent in other file

This is usefull for (at least) 2 situations

- when you want separate error from info and warns
- when you manage multiple processes and you need output from each process

ps. have questions ? feel free to ask! :)

Comment: This approach is good if you don't have common code, if you have 2 different log file for 2 different process, and both of the process have some common code then its a issue.

Answer (score 0):

Common convention is "a logger pr class and use the class name as its name".  This is good advice.

My personal experience is that this logger variable should NOT be declared static but an instance variable which is retrieved for each new.  This allows the logging framework to treat two calls differently depending on where they come from.  A static variable is the same for ALL instances of that class (in that class loader).

Also you should learn all the possibilities with your logging backend of choice.  You may have possibilities you did not expect possible.

Comment: Just a note, for log4j at least, if you are using the class name as the look up then it will be the same logger instance every time.  No reason to grab it again and again for each class instance.  You might as well keep it statically.

Comment: There are pros and cons for having static loggers.  They can be problematic in managed containers and they shouldn't be used at all in code intended to run inside OSGi.  See SLF4J's pros and cons: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static

Answer (score 0):

When deploying multiple EARs / WARs, it may be better to package the log4j.jar higher up in the classloader hierarchy.

i.e. not in WAR or EAR, but in the System-classloader of your container, otherwise multiple Log4J instances will write to the same file concurrently leading to strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is following SOA principles, for every service A you'll have the following components:

1. A Controller
2. A Service Implementation
3. A Executor
4. A Persistance

So it makes life easier to have a 
    aController.log
    aService.log
    aExecutor.log
    and aPersistance.log

This is a layer based separation so all your Remoting/REST/SOAP classes will write to the aController.log

All your scheduling mechanism, backend service etc will write to aService.log

And all task executions are written to aExecutor.log and so on.

If you have a multi-threaded executor you might have to use a log accumulator or another technique to properly align log messages for multiple threads.

This way you'll always have 4 log files which is not alot and not too less, I'm telling you from experience this makes life really easier.