# Can I write multiple messages to a database using log4j?

Tags: database, logging, log4j

Pretty new to all this so excuse any beginner mistakes.

I was wondering if I was able to get log4j to write multiple messages to the same db record in a single log write. example

log.debug("Message 1" , "Message 2");
or
log.debug("Message 1" , 7);

Can log4j only take a single message for writing?

Thanks

Comment: Corrected my answer, I was wrong about JDBC appender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a predefined [appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html) for it (`org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`), but it has limits, check the [API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html).

As for the second part of your question, each call to `Logger.debug/info/warn`, etc., causes a `LoggingEvent` object to be created in log4j internals, which is a "unit of logging". Log4j does not append anything to this object later, just logs it and forgets it.

If you need to merge a complicated text and log it as one, you should use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770076/log4j-strategies-for-creating-logger-instances/1802473#1802473), or better use log4j with slf4j, which can construct log strings with `{}` placeholders, sort of like C function `printf`.