# Access logger in different class

Tags: java, logging

I have created a logger in my main class as:

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( MainClass.class.getName());
```

I declared it public static.

this is log4j.properties:

## Root logger option

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
```

## Direct log messages to a log file

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Now i want to access this logger object in different class. 
When i tried giving logger directly it is giving error though i made it public static.

Below is my class from which i am trying to access logger object:

```
public class Db_Connector 
{
     MainClass.logger <------error
     //create ResultSet Class Object
     public ResultSet GetDataFromDB(){

        ResultSet resultset = null;
         try {  

                DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());   
                System.out.println("Connecting to the database...");   
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:Db", "User","pass01");
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();   
                resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from employee"); 

            } 
         catch (Exception e) {   
                System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e);   
                            } 

         return resultset;
        }   
}
```

Comment: What error do you have, and how are you trying to access the logger?

Comment: In another class i am trying MainClass.logger

Comment: What's the Exception when you call MainClass.logger - it's almost impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: May I ask, why you want to share your logger instance between the classes? Typically you create one instance per class, so usually there is no need to share it. Discussed here for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770076/log4j-strategies-for-creating-logger-instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Class that wraps up your Logger is also public

Comment: Would you please provide code section of where you are trying to access your logger

Comment: You can't call `MainClass.logger` in that location where you mark it as error
you should be able to access it normally inside a method `MainClass.Logger.something()...` ie: inside `GetDataFromDB()`

Answer (score 0):

You should create `public static` variable in your DB_Connector class and assign MainClass.logger to it.