# Performance by using one logger object per application in Java

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j, performance-testing

There are number of method to create logger instance.

1. one instance of Logger **per class**
2. one instance of Logger **per thread**
3. one instance of Logger **per application**

Can any one suggest performance on each method?

Currently i am using one logger object per application so Is this down multithreaded application performance?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log4J: Strategies for creating Logger instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770076/log4j-strategies-for-creating-logger-instances)

Comment: @AkashYadav Thanks , I have read that question and answer but can't able to analyze performance hit on each method.
My view point if i make Logger per application then it down application performance.

Answer (score 1):

A good tracking resource is Jamon, I guess you know it. Inside an EE application there is a simple way to "hook" it to every **method call**, in order to trace all method's execution time. In this way, you could analyze the impact of your "added" log calls

Back to your question, I don't think there should be performance issues, as the log output is anyway serialized and instantiating per method, classs or even application is just a matter of used memory